# Typing Autofill form

Tags: javascript, autofill

I've tried to Google my answer but I'm having no luck, I have a form on my website but I want it to auto-fill.

e.g. in the colour category box, the user can type "r" and Red with be available to select, if there is more than one option with red than the user will have to type the second character to choose because it will give all the colours beginning with "r".

I do not want to use a drop-box/check box etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, i don't think anyone's going to give you a detailed answer.

I advise you to check jqueryUI and it's Autocomplete widget.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
It's very easy to use...

Answer (score 0):

you can use Auto complete javascript text field.
source is here http://www.vonloesch.de/node/18